# Error when trying to use through table for many to many relationships in Django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class State(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    iso = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name


class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    justification = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    area_hectares = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name


class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, through='Site_Region_Junction')

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name


class Site_Region_Junction:
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The above code is my models.py for an app called unesco inside a django project.

One site can have many regions and one region can have many sites. I have tried implementing this manytomany relationship with the through table just in case I have to add more attributes to the junction table. But I get an error when I run `python manage.py check`. The errors shown are :

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x7f9ba5dee950>: (models.E022) <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x7f9ba5dee950> contains a lazy reference to unesco.site_region_junction, but app 'unesco' doesn't provide model 'site_region_junction'.
unesco.Region.sites: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'Site_Region_Junction', which has not been installed.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Removing the through table fixes the issues but I want to implement the through table.

Can anyone point out the mistakes I am making?

Comment: you are not extending models.Model class

Comment: oh my god I could not believe I missed that. Thank you for the help!